# Highcharts - Calculate avg interval "on the fly"

Tags: highcharts

I use Highcharts and I have an array of 60 data values (one per day).

I want to calculate the average value for an interval of 7 days (a week) and print only this average:

Highcharts offers a possibility to do this "on the fly" or I must calculate separately and add the calculated (average) values?

The best thing to have in my case, is to have an average value on default zoom and when the user zoom-in the data change on the correct day value (no average).

Comment: Something like this is part of Highchartock called dataGrouping. In Highcharts you have to calculate that on your own.

Comment: @PawełFus thanks for the reply, I was thinking that Highcharts offer a method to do this too